# MFC AfxParseURL reverse function?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there reverse function to MFC AfxParseURL (which creates URL from service type, port and so on)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AfxParseURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs1z60t6.aspx) is a wrapper around the [InternetCrackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384376.aspx)  function in `<wininet.h>`. The reverse function is [InternetCreateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384473.aspx), but MFC does not provide a wrapper for this.

You could either use `InternetCreateUrl` directly or create your own wrapper function that takes `CString` objects as input, initialises a `URL_COMPONENTS` structure, calls `InternetCreateUrl`, and returns the result as a `CString`.